# zsh: permission denied: after npm link

Tags: npm, hyperlink, console, command-line-interface, zsh

I am trying to run basic CLI command, but after **`npm link`** getting:

```
zsh: permission denied: testcom
```

File **myfile** contains:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ node


console.log('Hello!')
```

Running **`ls -alh`**:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 markhorton  staff    46B  4 Dec 20:37 myfile
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "katya",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "testcom": "myfile"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

However, running `testcom` says permission is denied.

Would be vey grateful for any help or suggestions. 
Thank you very much,
Katya

Comment: There's a stray space in your shebang; it should be `#!/usr/local/bin/node`. You're getting an error in trying to execute the directory `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: `myfile` also has to have execute permission set.

Comment: @chepner thank you so much, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

As @chepner said, the JavaScript file you are trying to run must have execute permissions on it.

```
$ chmod +x myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

If your permissions get missed up, you can unlink and relink to fix the problem. (I have even had npm permissions get messed up after an OS update.)

```
npm unlink -g
npm link
```